# How to include spring-restdocs into the war file?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restdocs

What are the steps to include the generated spring-restdocs into a war file?

Comment: This reads like a question, whereas I think it's the question "How to include REST Docs into the war file" and an answer to that question. @SuryaChinta, are you able to edit your question and split it up so that the answer is posted as an answer?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson : Made the necessary changes to post it in a question/answer format.

Answer (score 0):

Following the below steps, i was able to integrate rest docs into the war file.

1. Follow the instructions on the spring [website](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/) to configure your project to generate the doc file and also writing test cases that produce documentation. Once the initial set up is done, the next step is to integrate the documentation into the war file, for which you can follow the below instructions:
2. Create a SpringMvcConfiguration

   ```
       @EnableWebMvc

       public class SpringMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
           "classpath:/resources/" };
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

       if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
           registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                   CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
       }
         }
       }
   ```
3. update the pom.xml to include the plugins  for ascii doc, copy-resources

   ```
                 <build>
                 .....
                     <plugins>
                           <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                           <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>1.5.2</version>
                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>generate-docs</id>
                                   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                                   </goals>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <backend>html</backend>
                                       <doctype>book</doctype>
                                       <sourceDirectory>src/main/asciidoc</sourceDirectory>
                                       <attributes>
                                           <snippets>${snippetsDirectory}</snippets>
                                       </attributes>
                                   </configuration>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>
                       </plugin>
                       <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.7</version>
                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>copy-resources</id>
                                   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                   </goals>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <outputDirectory>
                                           ${project.build.outputDirectory}/public/docs
                                       </outputDirectory>
                                       <resources>
                                           <resource>
                                               <directory>
                                                   ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                               </directory>
                                           </resource>
                                       </resources>
                                   </configuration>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>
                       </plugin>
                   </plugins>
               </build>
   ```

   The plugin entries takes care of generating the documentation and adding it to the target/classes folder . In this case under target/classes/public/docs.

   4. Finally when you deploy the war file the documentation is available under http://://docs/
      In my case i created the index.adoc file and it generated index.html as the final output.